# Spawning a kernel mode thread - Windows

Tags: windows, multithreading, kernel, wdk

I have intensive processing that I need to perform in a device driver, at DISPATCH_LEVEL or lower IRQL.

- How do I create a kernel-thread?
- What IRQL does it run at? Can I control this?
- How is it scheduled? Because I am thinking from a user-mode perspective here, what priority does it run at?
- What kernel functions can I use to provide locking / synchronization?

Comment: This is all covered by the WDK docs.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff543102%28v=VS.85%29.aspx etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create system thread with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) As you can see one of its parameters is a start routine which can hold custom code - in it you can use [KeRaiseIrql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553079%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [KeLowerIrql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). By default threads will run in PASSIVE_LEVEL. ["Locks, Deadlocks, and Synchronization"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487425) is a very helpful paper regarding synchronization in kernel on windows and everyone who has to do some tinkering with the windows kernel should read or at least skim it

Comment: How do I know if I am running "in the system process context"? I am using the NDIS drivers so I don't know if their API callbacks call me from the system process or not.

Comment: If you read 1 row down: For Windows Vista and later versions of Windows, the handle will be a kernel handle. That is always use OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE